# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id' discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im trying to make a discord.py function that creates a 'secret' channel with the name of a user but whenever i run the function

i get this error

> in _create_channel parent_id = category.id if category else None AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

idek why theres an int or id error since im not trying to use either object or attribute

heres the code:

```
@client.command()
async def channel(ctx, user : discord.User):
  perms = {
    ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)}
  await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("♥~ " + user.name +" ~♥", category=category, overwrites = perms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `category` is the category id. You need to get the [CategoryChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=category#discord.CategoryChannel) object from `ctx.guild.categories` and pass that as `category` in `create_text_channel()`.

```
category_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=category)
await ctx.guild.create_text_channel("♥~ " + user.name +" ~♥", category=category_channel, overwrites = perms)
```

Comment: you're a life saver, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 await ctx.guild.create_text_channel('♥~ " + user.name +" ~♥', category=category, overwrites = perms)
```

Comment: wouldn't that just make it name the channel(♥~ " + user.name +" ~♥)??

Comment: it wont i guess

Comment: you dont seem too sure about your reply. anyways, i tried it and it didnt work bc nothing was changed except the entire name was put into quotes which changed the user.name from a user object to a single string containing everything within the ' ' including the pluses and quotation marks